# Arduino IDE crashes on Ubuntu 14.04 Java Error

Tags: java, arduino, ubuntu-14.04

1. I just downloaded Arduinoe ID 1.6.8 from [arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc) .
2. Placed it in home folder
3. Then ran command ./arduino .

The Error that occurred:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 

org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
    at processing.app.helpers.PreferencesMap.load(PreferencesMap.java:76)
    at processing.app.PreferencesData.init(PreferencesData.java:53)
    at processing.app.BaseNoGui.initParameters(BaseNoGui.java:993)
    at processing.app.Base.guardedMain(Base.java:159)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:137)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's still actual or not I answer anyway.
I met the same problem after a dist-upgrade. The solution for me was just to upgrade openjdk from 6th to 7th version:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-lib openjdk-7-jre-headless
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-6-jre-headless
```